# User with Send on Behalf can Send As

Tags: exchange-2013, outlook-2013, email

USING M-EXCH 2013 AND OUTLOOK 2013

I have created a brand new user, 'test', that has no special permissions in exchange,
I have specified that this user can send on behalf of another user, 'Support'.
When 'test' selects the  'support' account in the from dropdown and send a message, the recipients of the email see the email as though it is from 'support' not from 'test' on behalf of 'support'.

I'm stuck please help :S

Comment: Does "Test" also have the "Full Mailbox Access" permission on "Support"?

Comment: No, Just Send on Behalf

Comment: Definitely not out of the box functionality as much as I can say.
Could you please provide output of the following command in EMS:
Get-ADPermission -Identity support